# Full text API for tags

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting started on Full text API. I was using a indexed pattern and I was suggested to use Full text API to prevent exploding indexes. I need help in conceptualization.

My app is CRM - list. It has contacts and each contact can have 5-10 tags and a date created.

I know I can do an AND or OR operations on various fields but I am not sure how to setup the document for searching something like the following

Search for all contacts with Tag1 and Tag2 but not with Tag3

Should I be using atom or create multiple fields in the document with the same name as tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not one tags field as TextField:

```
search.TextField(name='tags', value='tag1 tag2')
```

and query:

```
tags:(tag1 AND tag2) AND (NOT tags:tag3)
```

Comment: Since tags can have spaces, one tag can be a subset of another. Eg: no payment, payment in march - I cannot say payment in march and not of payment..

Comment: so normalize them when indesing and then before searching for them.

Comment: I am using URLEncode to normalize my strings. Perhaps that's an issue.  "Not paid" becomes not+paid. While, I am searching for paid", I get not+paid too. Should I be looking elsewhere to do normalization.

Comment: thats not true. if you index 'not+paid' and search for 'paid' you won't get the document back. i just tested it! you must have another issue going on

Comment: I just tried it again. I have these tags in one of the test records - tags  TEXT  not+paid test AgileCrm not+paid+in+March - when I am querying using ..search("tags:" + URLEncoder.encode("paid")) - I get to see the not+paid as well. Totally stumped. Thanks.

Comment: from this last answer i don't understand if now it works for you or not.

Comment: It does not work. Can you copy your tags data from index? Perhaps urlencode could be an issue there. Java URLEncode puts a + while some implementations put %20 - would like to see what you see in your indexed data in admin console. Thanks.

Comment: i use python and i did not explicitly urlencoded the tags. i indexed 1 document with `paid` and the other one with `not+paid` and by searching for `paid` i get only 1 document and the other way around.